# Node.js loop printing in wrong order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to show some data from a couple of files in a directory, however there contents are printing out in the wrong order.

```
fs.readdir('files/sets', function(err, files){  
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){  
        console.log("_______________________________");
        readFile(files[i]);
    }
});

function readFile(file){
    csv()
    .from.path('files/training_set/'+file, {delimiter: ','})
    .transform(function(row){
        console.log(row);
    });
}
```

each file contains two lines:

File One:

```
John:
Hey there!
```

File Two:

```
Mary:
Whats up!
```

I would expect the output to be something like

```
____________________
John
Hey there!
____________________
Mary
Whats up!
```

But I actually get

```
____________________
____________________
John
Mary
Hey there! 
Whats up!
```

I have been searching and think its something to do with asynchronous function and the loop being to fast. But I cant seem to fix the problem. I have tried the following method, but results are the same.

```
fs.readdir('files/sets', function(err, files){  
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){  
        (function(j){  
            console.log("_______________________________");
            readFile(files[j]);
        })(i)
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks more like you're expecting node to read the files in some given order, and it doesn't ?

Comment: correct, I am expecting it to print the line, read one file, print another line, then read the next file.

Comment: Well, yes, but read the files in what order, how do you know readdir reads the files in the directory in the order you're expecting it to. Sort the files array before you iterate to solve this, but you'll have to tell us what order you're expecting, by filename ?

Comment: Oh, I see now, you're getting a result that makes no sense based on the files you have, and that is indeed a strange result, but it's due to the fact that readFile function has async code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readFile` is an async operation and you are trying to run it synchronously without waiting for the callback to finish:

```
var async = require('async'); // npm install async

fs.readdir('files/sets', function(err, files){
  async.eachSeries(files,readFile,function(err){
   // more async stuff ...
  });
});

function readFile(file,callback){
    console.log("_______________________________");
    csv()
    .from.path('files/training_set/'+file, {delimiter: ','})
    .transform(function(row){
        console.log(row);
    }).on('close',function() {
      callback();
    });
}
```

Also, you have to run it in series if you need to wait to the previous file to finish.

Comment: Thankyou! I had looked into this module, but didnt use eachSeries. What is the purpose of the callback here? is it purely for errors?

Comment: In async operations you ALWAYS need the callback, no matter what. It's a way of saying "we are done running this block". If you don't call it it will just hang there forever. In the example, the `callback` is the function with the "// more async stuff" comment

Comment: Thanks, I have just read up on it some more here https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries - Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are seeing the result of asynchronous processing. You don't want to write a line at a time, since you will generally get the output for the files interspersed. Instead, you only want to write the entire output for a file to the console in a single call to console.log.

I think this should work:

```
fs.readdir('files/sets', function(err, files){
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        readFile(files[i]);
    }
});

function readFile(file){
    var outStr = "_______________________________";
    csv()
    .from.path('files/training_set/'+file, {delimiter: ','})
    .transform(function(row){
        outStr += '\n' + row;
    })
    .on('end', function(){
        console.log(outStr);
    });
}
```